# Karma webpack mocha reporter. The error stack is not formatted

Tags: webpack, karma-runner

I am testing the JS code bundled by Webpack that has been transformed by Babel in Karma where Mocha makes reports.
[image]
From all of this I need only.[image]
I apply sourcemap processing [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-webpack#source-maps).
I will be pleased for any tip.